# aubin-lion lemma

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ and we have 
$$u_n \rightarrow u \mbox{ in } L^{\infty}(0,T;H^2(\Omega)) \mbox{ weak star }$$
and
$$\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial t} \rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \mbox{ in } L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(\Omega))$$
then, using Classical Aubin-Lions Compactness, we have
$$u_n \rightarrow u \mbox{ in } C([0,T];H^{2-\varepsilon}(\Omega)),\ \  \forall \varepsilon >0, \mbox{ and  almost everywhere}.$$

My question is that how he get this result? and how he use the aubin-lion lemma to get into it?

Comment: Excuse me, can you give a proof now? I really need it. Thanks!

Comment: I can send you the aubin's lion compactness lemma if you want?? @ylath

Comment: @Ylath all the proof depend on this lemma